# Maven dependencies for Clojure libraries on GitHub

Tags: clojure, build-process, maven, github, m2eclipse

I'm developing some applications in Clojure + Java using Eclipse and Maven with m2eclipse.

This works great when my dependencies are in a Maven repository. However there are some libraries that I would like to use that aren't in any repository - e.g. small open source Clojure libraries hosted on GitHub.

These projects typically have a build.xml or a project.clj but not a pom.xml.

Is there a any way to set up Maven to handle these dependencies automatically? Or do I need to manually download and build all of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you'll either have to:

- find a repository containing those libraries
- manually add these to your repository using mvn install (and if you're kind enough, ask for those to be published in the central maven repo)
- ask the developers if they would be so kind to propose a mavenized version and publish it in some maven repository

Answer (score 2):

Clojure libraries often provide their artifacts in [clojars](http://clojars.org/), you might solve your issues just by adding it as a repository in your pom.xml.

Another option available when integrating leiningen and maven builds is to automatically generate a POM out of a project.clj via `lein pom`

This would allow to include the libraries in your build as long as you checked them out locally.